# Def in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am struggling to understand the python function in the following code:

```
def sample(k):
  if(k>0):
    result = k+sample(k-1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

sample(6)
```

Out:

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
```

I don't believe I understand how the function works. I expected the output to be 11(=6+55). Can someone explain what aspect of how this function works?

Edit: I meant 11(=6+5) not 11(=6+55)

Comment: What do you mean `11(=6+55)`?

Comment: Also, you're missing the final output unless you do `print(sample(6))`

Comment: The result, 21, is 6+5+4+3+2+1.  Please explain your expectation?

Comment: @cricket_007 I suspect `6+55` is a typo for `6+5`.

Comment: You should review a chapter about recursion in a programming textbook.

Comment: @U9-Forward why you edited out the OP's expectation?? don't do that.

Comment: @wim Ugh, my bad, i wasn't paying attention, :-)

Comment: @wim Edited mine.

Comment: It's because of the recursion fairy.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on this

```
def sample(k):
  if(k>0):
    result = k+sample(k-1)
```

Maybe even re-write it so it is clearer

```
def sample(k):
  if(k>0):
    _next = sample(k-1)
    print("{}+{}".format(k, _next))
```

<sub>And note that `k` can never be negative</sub>

And you'll see a pattern, to which the final result is `21`, not `11`, and not sure where `55` came from, either

```
1+0
2+1
3+3
4+6
5+10
6+15
```

What is happening is *recursion*, and the function is counting down from `6...0`, and returns back to the calling execution point, then adds back `1+k` for when `k==0`, then `2+(1+0)` when `k==1`, and so on... and the results are calcuated just like you would have learned in math classes about order of operations

This continues on to be `3+(2+(1+0))`, `4+(3+(2+(1+0)))`, until you get back to `k==6`, the initial input

Answer (score 0):

Your function is recursive - meaning it calls itself and keeps calling itself until some condition arises. In your case, it keeps calling itself with lower values for `k` until it reaches 0, which is when it returns 0.

Since you print the result *after* every recursive call to the function itself, it will print all the results in reverse order. Consider this: getting called with `k=6` will first call it with `k=5`, which will first call it with `k=4`, etc. and only when it first returns `0`, will something get printed after the call with `k=1` and then the result for `k=2`, etc.

This explains what it prints, it is really `1` because you don't print `0`, then `3` because that's `1+2`, then `6` because that's `3+3`, then `6+4`, `10+5` and finally `15+6`.

If you only want it to print the final result, you should just print the result as it is returned by the first call:

```
print(sample(6))
```

And remove the print statement in the function.

Comment: Note that this would print 21, correctly, since the result you expect would only cover the last two calls, as if the entire chain down to 0 didn't happen - which is not what this function does.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what's happening here

```
def sample(k): #1
    if(k>0): #2
        result = k+sample(k-1) #3
        print(result) #4
    else: #5
        result = 0 #6 
    return result #7

sample(6)
```

I put line number to make it easily tractable. When you call `sample(6)`, it will see `6>0` so it will call `sample(5)` in line 3. It will do it until it reaches `sample(0)`. In case of sample(0), it will return 0, and print nothing. Then for `sample(1)`, it will print 1 and return 1. Then for `sample(2)`, it will return `1+2` and print 3. Similarly, for `sample(3)` returns 6, for `sample(4)` returns 10, for `sample(5)` returns 15, and finally, for `sample(6)` returns 21.

Answer (score 0):

This function essentially just adds up all the numbers between 0 and the number you give it. Here you have given it 6 so it will return 1+2+3+4+5+6=21

Each of the print statements will print its current total. As there is recursion involved the algorithm cannot work out 6+sample(5) without working out sample(5) and cannot work out 5+sample(4) without finding sample(4) and so on. This continues until it reaches sample(0) which always returns 0. It can then find sample(1) and sample(2) and so on until the final result of sample(6).

Answer (score 0):

Your function is under recursion issue. Actually, its return order is from 1 to 6.